# Using chrome, my site works fine. Using IE the mouseover doesnt work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

so here is my code:

```
<th width="14%" height="63" scope="col">
    <img 
        src="GFX/home-navi.fw.png" 
        width="140" height="63" 
        onmouseover="this.src='GFX/home-navi-mo.fw.png';" />
</th>
```

The mouseover works perfectly on Chrome but not IE. How can i fix?

Comment: Do you get any console errors in IE? Also maybe set IE's options to alert for all script errors.

Comment: Make sure you're not in quirks mode in IE.  see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547565/mouse-over-effect-is-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @Freethinker, which missing quotes you are talking about ?

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 Nevermind, I didn't scroll left...

Answer (score 0):

just for information:

[Docs for IE Mouseover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

anyway you would give [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) a try:

```
The mouseenter JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer. 
Because of the event's general utility,     
jQuery simulates this event so that it can be used regardless of browser. 
This event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element.
Any HTML element can receive this event.
```

but with my IE8 it works like this

```
<body>
<table>
    <th width="14%" height="63" scope="col">
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo6w.png" width="100" height="50"     onmouseover="this.src='http://gameplayer-magazine.de/WordPress/wp-content/gallery/google/google-2.jpg';">
    </th>
    </table>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2Z7f/1/)

maybe your resources are not online?

i think it would be really helpfull if you tell us which IE version you might use?

kindly

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CSS` to show hover effect:

```
<th width="14%" height="63" scope="col">
      <img class="img" width="140" height="63"/>
</th>

<style>
    .img
    {
        background:url(GFX/home-navi.fw.png);
    }  
    .img:hover
    {
        background:url(GFX/home-navi-mo.fw.png);
    }  
</style>
```